# What is the best way to avoid this artifact (<!-- -->) in a NextJS build output?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm doing some work on a nextjs build output and I'm seeing this artifact 
in places where I have spaces for example:

`<span id="phone-number">Phone: <!-- -->511-111-1111</span>`

It can also be generated from an empty string used as spaces in the codebase like this

`<span id="name">Name: {' '} John Doe</span>`

On the build output, that line will become this:

`<span id="name">Name: <!-- --> John Doe</span>`

But other times it is random, how can I avoid this artifact?

Comment: Those are called comment tags.  What version of Next.js are you using?  There was a bug in v12.1.4.  See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36998  Fixed in v12.1.5

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Ah thanks, I didn't know their name, the version I'm using is 14.0.3